# Html code is working in IE 8 not with other browsers. The width of the shape i not working

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Below code is working in IE8 but not in other browsers. The main problem is with the width.The size of shape i used is working in IE8 but not with other browsers. How can I make this code compatible with all browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="author" content="Shivakumar">
<meta name="generator" content="">
<style type="text/css"> 
/*----------Text Styles----------*/
.ws6 {font-size: 8px;}
.ws7 {font-size: 9.3px;}
.ws8 {font-size: 11px;}
.ws9 {font-size: 12px;}
.ws10 {font-size: 13px;}
.ws11 {font-size: 15px;}
.ws12 {font-size: 16px;}
.ws14 {font-size: 19px;}
.ws16 {font-size: 21px;}
.ws18 {font-size: 24px;}
.ws20 {font-size: 27px;}
.ws22 {font-size: 29px;}
.ws24 {font-size: 32px;}
.ws26 {font-size: 35px;}
.ws28 {font-size: 37px;}
.ws36 {font-size: 48px;}
.ws48 {font-size: 64px;}
.ws72 {font-size: 96px;}
.wpmd {font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-    weight: normal;}
/*----------Para Styles----------*/
DIV,UL,OL /* Left */
{
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body bgColor="#FFFFFF">
   <div id="shape1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:3px; top:50px;   width:993px; height:54px; z-index:0"><img border=0 width="100%" height="100%" alt=""       src="C:\Documents and Settings\snatarajan\Desktop\s\shapeSTUKG.gif"></div>

 <select name="formselect1" style="position:absolute;left:665px;top:65px;width:134px;z-     index:1">
 <option value="option1">option 1</option>
 <option value="option2">option 2</option>
 </select>
 <input name="formtext1" type="text" style="position:absolute;width:433px;left:199px;top:64px;z-index:2">
 <input name="formbutton1" type="button" value="Go!" style="position:absolute;left:822px;top:65px;z-index:3">
 <div id="text1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:53px; top:65px; width:114px; height:90px; z-index:4">
 <div class="wpmd">
 <div><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Book Antiqua" class="ws12" style="background- color:#99CCFF;"><B>type here</B></font></div>
 </div></div>

 <div id="hr1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:2px; top:104px;   width:994px; height:21px; z-index:5">
 <hr size=2 width=994 color="#99CCFF">
 </div>

 <div id="text2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:799px; top:19px;  width:55px; height:19px; z-index:6">
 <a href="ss_signup.html" target="iFrame1"><div class="wpmd">
 <div><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Calibri" style="background-color:#99CCFF;"><B>New  User</B></font></div>
 </div></a></div>

 <div id="text3" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:883px; top:19px; width:45px; height:21px; z-index:7">
 <a href="ss_signin.html" target="iFrame1"><div class="wpmd">
 <div><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Calibri" style="background-color:#99CCFF;"><B>Sign- in</B></font></div>
 </div></a></div>

 <div id="text4" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:863px; top:21px; width:10px; height:18px; z-index:8">
 <div class="wpmd">
 <div><font color="#3366FF" face="Calibri">|</font></div>
 </div></div>

 <div id="text5" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:780px; top:20px;  width:10px; height:19px; z-index:9">
 <div class="wpmd">
 <div><font color="#3366FF" face="Calibri">|</font></div>
 <div><font face="Calibri"><BR></font></div>
 </div></div>

 <div id="text6" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:738px; top:19px;    width:37px; height:20px; z-index:10">
 <div class="wpmd">
 <div><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Calibri" style="background- color:#99CCFF;"><B>Home</B></font></div>
 <div><font color="#99CCFF" face="Calibri" style="background- color:#FFFFFF;"><BR></font></div>
  </div></div>

  <div id="iFrame1" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:113px; z-index:11">
  <iframe name="iFrame1" width="988" height="647" src="" scrolling="no"   frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have no Doctype, this will trigger [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) in which browsers emulate bugs in older browsers. One of these bugs, in IE, is that it gets the CSS `width` property wrong.

Add a Doctype that triggers standards mode. This will add a great deal of consistency. You can then adjust the CSS to fix it.

Doctypes that trigger standards mode include the ones from the latest HTML specification, and the draft HTML 5 specification:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You should also validate your [html](http://validator.w3.org) and [css](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: I've tried with the doctype in my code its not working. do i need to do anything with width?

Comment: Yes, you need to use it correctly (remembering that it refers to content width, not the space between the borders).

Answer (score 0):

You have some whitespaces inside your CSS (in the `<style>` tag and in the inline styles). For example, you have to change the following line

```
.wpmd {font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-    weight: normal;}
```

to

```
.wpmd {font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;}
```

Note the whitespaces between "font-" and "weight" at the end. 
Similar errors appear on multiple entries.

In Firefox you can see those CSS (and later on JS as well) errors by using CTRL + SHIFT + K .

Comment: Thanks Sirko. I corrected but it is not working with other browsers.Width i am facing the problem